# Want to instantiatate an object with enum but can't figure out how to

Tags: c#, arrays, enums

I have a car class which needs a brand, a type, and the make, for example, SUV, coupe, sedan. I made an enum class for these types. I want to instantiate a new car which needs these arguments. I have to import these data from a text file. The text file contains this: &Peugeot*406%sedan$2002/110. I split the pieces of information into a string array but don't know how to get the make of the car. I hope you understand my problem here is the code :

```
 Car car = new Car(data[0],data[1],int.Parse(data[2]),int.Parse(data[3]),int.Parse(data[4]));
```

Comment: You are probably looking for Enum.Parse

Comment: "No overload for method 'Parse' that takes 1 arguments"

Comment: @D.Tomi That's right - [read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2). You need to pass in the _type_ of enum as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the strings into enum equivalents. It is better to use TryParse to avoid exceptions.

Here's a simple example especially written for you :)

```
enum AutoBrand { Skoda, Toyota, BMW};
enum AutoType { SUV, SEDAN, HATCHBACK};

static void Main(string[] args)
{

string[] strAutoBrands = new string[] { "Skoda", "Toyota", "BMW" };
string[] strAutoTypes = new string [] { "SUB", "SEDAN", "HATCHBACK" };

foreach(var autoBrandVal in strAutoBrands)
{
    AutoBrand b = (AutoBrand) Enum.Parse(typeof(AutoBrand), autoBrandVal);

    Console.WriteLine($"Auto brand is: {b}");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enums are typically used to define a set of constants to use instead of "magic numbers" to make *code* mode human-readable. They may not be appropriate to use for string-based data like make and model.

However, if you have a string and want to find the equivalent Enum value, use [`Enum.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
 Car car = new Car(
    Enum.Parse(typeof(Make),data[0]),
    Enum.Parse(typeof(Model),data[1]),
    int.Parse(data[2]),
    int.Parse(data[3]),
    int.Parse(data[4]));
```

Note that you should add appropriate error hendling, etc. to deal with invalid string values.

Comment: Didn't work, but anyways thanks for the help, i will try to solve it.

Comment: What didn't work? You didn't provide much code so I had to guess on the types of make and model.

Comment: It's hard because i am from Hungary and i wrote the code in hungarian :/ i will try to contact my teacher about it.

Comment: Two things, first try data[0].Trim() to remove any extra spaces.  Second, try to use TryParse, it helps against exceptions.